# Use Reverse Tethering as Wifi

Tags: reverse-tether

The internet obtained via reverse tethering is not detected by my tablet.But i can access the web.But i cant download via the play store.So how to make it recognizable as a **wireless fidelity** connection ?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to use your computer as a wireless access point?

Answer (score 0):

simply download wifi hotspot. this may help you convert your pc onto a wifi hotspot and then you can share your internet connection on more than one android phone. it even runs on java phone which supports wifi. but if you have  windows xp then you might get problems but if you have higher like windows 7 or 8 then it will run very swiftly. 
here is a link you can use to download it

https://a1-downloads.phpnuke.org/en/c151454/wifi-hotspot-creator-free-download-full-review